# does FDT platform has a jangaroo implementation

Tags: fdt

I'd like to know if FDT has implementation of jangaroo - the as 2 js compiler.
For several years i use the FDT as my coding tool. now when the world mooves to html5 i am interested in finding a good solution for coding JS. does FDT has that?

Answer (score 0):

FDT does not support [Jangaroo](http://www.jangaroo.net/home/). Only Flash via [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) and [MXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MXML); it also supports working with [Haxe](http://haxe.org/).